# Python - Interate and compare over list and dict in dict in parallel

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, if-statement

I want to iterate over a list and a dict in a dict in parallel and find the same strings. If it found the same strings I want to add a value and key pair to the dicts I was iterating over.

I sadly can't get it to work. I simplified the problem to make the code easier to exchange here.

```
x = ['a', 'c', 'f', 'h']
y = {'root_name': [
        {'value01': 'key01', 'value02': 'a'},
        {'value01': 'key02', 'value02': 'b'},
        {'value01': 'key03', 'value02': 'c'},
        {'value01': 'key04', 'value02': 'd'},
        {'value01': 'key05', 'value02': 'e'},
        {'value01': 'key06', 'value02': 'f'},
        {'value01': 'key07', 'value02': 'g'},
        {'value01': 'key08', 'value02': 'h'},
        {'value01': 'key09', 'value02': 'i'},
        {'value01': 'key10', 'value02': 'j'}
                   ]}

for i, j in zip(x, y['root_name']):
    if i == j['value02']:
        y['root_name']['key_exists'] = True
```

Comment: "in parallel" may imply multiple threads which wouldn't help. Perhaps that first sentence should be _I want to iterate over a list and a dict in a dict to find matching strings_.  Does that sound accurate?

Comment: Are the matching strings always in `value02`?

Comment: In your example, what is the expected output? Do you only want to compare the first 4 dicts in the "root_name" list sequentially against the 4 values in `x`?

Comment: Depending on your goals, it may be as simple as replacing `y['root_name']['key_exists'] = True` with `j['key_exists'] = True`. Then that first dict in the list is `{'value01': 'key01', 'value02': 'a', 'key_exists': True}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to place key_exists in dictionaries where value of 'value02' exists in x.

```
x = ['a', 'c', 'f', 'h']
y = {'root_name': [
        {'value01': 'key01', 'value02': 'a'},
        {'value01': 'key02', 'value02': 'b'},
        {'value01': 'key03', 'value02': 'c'},
        {'value01': 'key04', 'value02': 'd'},
        {'value01': 'key05', 'value02': 'e'},
        {'value01': 'key06', 'value02': 'f'},
        {'value01': 'key07', 'value02': 'g'},
        {'value01': 'key08', 'value02': 'h'},
        {'value01': 'key09', 'value02': 'i'},
        {'value01': 'key10', 'value02': 'j'}
                   ]}

    set_x = set(x)  # To speed checking for presence (only useful for larger lists)
    for i in y['root_name']:
        if i['value02'] in set_x:
            i['key_exists'] = True

    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(y)
```

**Output**

```
{'root_name': [{'key_exists': True, 'value01': 'key01', 'value02': 'a'},
               {'value01': 'key02', 'value02': 'b'},
               {'key_exists': True, 'value01': 'key03', 'value02': 'c'},
               {'value01': 'key04', 'value02': 'd'},
               {'value01': 'key05', 'value02': 'e'},
               {'key_exists': True, 'value01': 'key06', 'value02': 'f'},
               {'value01': 'key07', 'value02': 'g'},
               {'key_exists': True, 'value01': 'key08', 'value02': 'h'},
               {'value01': 'key09', 'value02': 'i'},
               {'value01': 'key10', 'value02': 'j'}]}
```

Comment: Very thankful for that answer :). It worked like charm and when looking at your example I see myself thinking way to complicated.